# Terraform: Destroying/Disabling azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, azure-ddos

I manage a Azure environment via Terraform and each one of them has DDOS Protection Plan enabled. I was instructed to disable and delete DDOS on all non-prod environment. The code is ready and the plan shows that the azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan will be destroyed and every virtual network with ddos will be updated in-place and disabled. The ddos_protection_plan section will become null.

The error I am receiving is

> network.DdosProtectionPlansClient#Delete: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="InUseDdosProtectionPlanCannotBeDeleted".

Problem: Terraform is trying to delete the azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan first.

Question: How do I force it to disable the ddosplan in each virtual network before destroying the resource. I've tested the depend_on but this causes cycle error. Also looked into the lifecycle block and did not seem to apply.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Additional info:

- the dynamic block for ddos plan in virtual network looks very similar to this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9113

Updates:

Terraform Version 0.13.7
AzureRM Provider Version: 3.13.0

Comment: Is this issue the same as yours? Does the proposed solution work for you? Which provider version are you using?

Comment: If you are referring to the link. My issue is different. They are trying to solve the dynamic block which I already had in place.   

My problem is Terraform trying to destroy the ddos resource while still enabled in each VNET.

Terraform Version 0.13.7
AzureRM Provider Version: 3.13.0